# CSS/JS: Evenly spreading elements across multiple lines

Tags: javascript, css

How would you go about evenly spreading elements across multiple lines, for example:

---

```
wrapper div: <div style="text-align: center">
elements inside: <div style="display: inline-block;
                 padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;">Element</div>
```

Instead of only having one element on the next line (wrapped):

```
Element 1        Element 2        Element 3        Element 4        Element 5
                          Element 6
```

It does this, spreading out the elements:

```
Element 1        Element 2        Element 3
Element 4        Element 5        Element 6
```

Comment: I made this not dynamic, couldn't find a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the width of the elements and their count is not fixed, I would write a code which generates custom markup depending on the situation.

However it may get tricky because with the web medium, it's hard (impossible actually) to calculate the actual size in pixels of a text block (no way of knowing what font will a browser use and get its metrics).

I'd suggest deciding on the number of columns in advance (2 or 3) then using elements with their width set to `50%` or `33%` and `text-align` property to `center`.

Comment: The elements could be really short or really long in my situation... possibly using JS to work out the size of each block?

Answer (score 0):

How about specifying "width" style?

```
<div style="width: 50px; display: inline-block; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;">Element</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Float them all left, width to 50% or 33% or whatever you need.

Make sure you clear the float afterwards.